# My data access request will be processed last year?

Tags: support, bug, legal, contact, gdpr

On October 4th I opened a GDPR Portability [request](/legal/gdpr/data-subjects) ("Export my data").

Today I received an email that my request will be processed and I will receive an answer on 3rd November 2018. This is also shown on the process overview page:

> Data Access Request: [redacted]
>
> Stack Overflow has accepted your request and it is currently being
>   processed. You can expect to hear back by Nov 3 '18.
>
> Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323840) to check on the
>   status of your request.
>
> If you have additional questions, please reply to this email and
>   someone from our privacy team can assist you.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The Stack Overflow Team

**Unfortunately this date is some three months ago.**

I think this error occured because the system assumes a shorter time for *Company approval requested* and therefore considers one month the request time.

A few screenshots illustrating the problem:

1. GDPR request page: [image]
2. GDPR single request overview page: [image]
3. The e-mail: [image]

<sup>The Reference ID has been removed of all pictures. Don't wonder about the free space. :)</sup>

Comment: Weird. We can’t even write that off to a time zone problem unless somehow it’s converting to Martian lander time.

Comment: @ColleenV and also rather not caching as I only received the email today.

Comment: Just FYI: My data access request has been fulfilled/completed now. This still doesn't fix the issue of course :)

Comment: Looking into it, there was an issue with processing some requests and after we kicked it, it looks like some dates got screwed up along the way.